# A word that means: "to break someone's lie"? I want to aggressively point out that she or he is lying

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests

What word (or expression) can I use that means “to break someone's lie”?

I mean to aggressively point out that she or he is lying.

> She stood up and ___ his lie/that he was a liar.

I'm thinking of *debunk*, but it doesn't seem suitable here.

Comment: I've edited the question. If you are unhappy with the edits you can click on *edit* and rollback to the previous version. I hope this helps.

Comment: How about decried?

Comment: consider "calling bullshit" or "I call bullshit!" in some situations, an extension of calling out a lie as per AP below.

Comment: Not sure if this is in the context you want so I did not add it as a question but you could say that you "caught them red handed"

Comment: Context would help.  Is this in the bedroom or the courtroom?  In a public debate or a hospital waiting room?

Comment: Do you mean she *accused* him of lying, or she *proved* that he lied?

Comment: She could stand up and _shatter_ his lie, perhaps?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You may want to consider using divulge or the phrase brought to light. Although, they are not very aggressive. A more aggressive term would be brand. As in , "She stood up and branded him a liar."

Answer (score 74):

You might say you "exposed" that person as a liar.

That works mostly if it is to a larger audience of people.  It loses some power if it's just two people arguing in a kitchen.  I guess the connotation is that this person was lying to many people, and you "exposed" her to all of them.

Comment: You can also "expose a lie" directly.

Answer (score 36):

Consider **"to call someone's lie"**:

> There are times when a subject may try to misinform you, even utter lies. In such cases, you don’t have to **call his lie**.
>
> ([easymedia.in](http://www.easymedia.in/6-more-useful-interview-tips/))

Another possibility was suggested in the comments: *to [call someone out](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/call+out)* (on their lie.)

> I didn't get mad, but could tell **he was lying** and later **called him out on it**.
>
> ([relationshiptalk.net](http://www.relationshiptalk.net/caught-my-boyfriend-in-a-lie-and-instead-of-talking-about-it-he-dumped-me.-27063528.html))

Also ***to call someone on their lie*** can be used (omitting the preposition "out"):

> Why did my boyfriend get so mad when **I exposed his lies**?
>
> So, why did your ex-boyfriend get so angry when **you called him on his lies**?
>
> ([truthaboutdeception.com](http://www.truthaboutdeception.com/community-features/ask-an-expert/questions-by-topic/lying/703-why-did-my-boyfriend-get-so-mad-when-i-exposed-his-lies.html))

(In the example above, the first line is a question, and the second is part of the answer restating the question in different words. I highlighted "expose" and "call out on" in bold to demonstrate parallelism. To show they mean the same thing.)

Comment: Also "to call them out (on their lie)." http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/call+out Definition #4

Comment: I've personally never heard "his lie" be the object of "call".  It's either "call him out" or "call his bluff".

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but "calling someone's lie" isn't a well known English idiom at all.  Google "call his lie" returns this page as the top hit.

Comment: "calling a lie" is a completely normal and common English phrase.

Comment: You shouldn't emphasise **exposed** in bold  making it look like an answer, when it has been suggested by @andy.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's to emphasize the parallelism. At the page I linked to the question uses "expose" and the answer uses "call out on". The parallelism leaves no doubt as to the meaning (see my updated answer.) I didn't mean to take away from Andy's answer, in fact, I upvoted it.

Comment: I upvoted both of yours for that matter :)

Answer (score 14):

Refute.

> to ​prove a ​statement, ​opinion, or ​belief to be ​wrong or ​false

(http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/refute)

"She stood up and refuted his lie."

Comment: "refute" would mean to prove the falsehood of the lie, not to expose the liar.

Comment: @anrderj - Excellent point. It's a fine distinction, but it makes a significant difference in terms of the question asked.

Comment: But if the second speaker isn't disproving the first statement, all she's doing is *contradicting* or *disputing* it, or *accusing* the first speaker of being a liar.  The question seems to be asking for something stronger than those.

Answer (score 8):

*She stood up and **denounced** him as a liar* or *She stood up and **denounced** his lies.*

You could even say *I denounce you as a liar!* or just *You liar!* or *You lie!*

When said strongly, additional words aren't really needed.

From Merriam-Webster (www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/denounce):

> [denounce](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/denounce)
>   1 : to pronounce especially publicly to be blameworthy or evil

And less so, but related:

> 3 : to inform against :  accuse

The word *decry* was mentioned, and is possible, but to me is not quite right, because that is (Merriam Webster) *express strong disapproval of* which isn't quite the same as saying that someone is lying/wrong/etc. (The person could be telling the truth and you still decry him.)

Answer (score 5):

You could *[give him the lie](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/To+give+the+lie+to)*

> To charge with falsehood; as, the man gave him the lie. [Webster's]

Comment: This feels archaic to me. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gave+him+the+lie%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cgave+him+the+lie%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgave%20him%20the%20lie%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgave%20him%20the%20lie%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @PeterShor, quite likely (I've been reading too much Rafael Sabatini recently).

Comment: Good for you! I've liked the Sabatini I've read; I should read more of him.

Answer (score 5):

She stood up and dismantled his lie.  More aggressively: she tore his lie apart or she made mincemeat of his lie.

Answer (score 3):

The first word that came to mind for me was: ***busted!***  Growing up in Southern California this was a term I heard all the time when someone was exposed as a liar.

Ex: [***Busted!*** Hillary's Benghazi lies go even deeper](http://www.wnd.com/2015/10/busted-hillarys-benghazi-lies-go-even-deeper/)

and:  [It Gets Worse For Republicans As GOP ***Busted*** For Lying About Access To Emails](http://www.politicususa.com/2015/10/20/worse-republicans-gop-busted-lying-access-emails.html)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to give him the lie, you can give the lie to [something].

> She stood up and gave the lie to his claims

source: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/give-the-lie-to-sth

Answer (score 1):

I would use "see through". She saw through his lie.

Comment: Your answer limits to the fact that she only understood that he was lying and may/may not have taken the decision to accuse him publicly after it. What the OP asked for is along the lines of 'publicly exposing' the lie, not just knowing it.

Comment: I would suggest "cut through".  She cut through his lie.

Comment: In that case I'd say "she exposed his lie".

Answer (score 1):

In some situations, "revealed" can work: "She stood up and revealed his lie".

However, this can imply that there was some preparation, and/or that the lying happened in the past. The reason is that "to reveal" means to make visible what was invisible before.

Answer (score 1):

I would say something like this:

```
She stood up and called him out on his lie.
She stood up and put him on blast for his lie.
```

Another good word would be 'refute'. It's similar to 'debunked', which you had mentioned.

> Refute: prove (a statement or theory) to be wrong or false; disprove.

source: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/refute

You could also use 'challenged' which is less assertive, or invalidate(d).

Comment: I've never heard of "putting someone on blast" before!

Comment: @ErikE - It's slang. [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=put+on+blast)

Comment: @NathanielMiller Related: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/6860/is-urban-dictionary-an-acceptable-source

Comment: When you quote, the source of the quote [needs to be included in plain text](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), preferably with a link. If this is from a Google definition, it's really from http://oxforddictionaries.com and *they* should get the credit.

Answer (score 1):

Shakespeare said, "to give someone the lie direct". The "lie direct" is a bold and barefaced lie. Accusing someone of the lie direct is a big takedown.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to propose "outed" or "indicted" as follows:

- She stood up and **indicted** him on his lie.
- She stood up and **outed** him on his lie.

Answer (score 1):

You could also say that you **"caught him out in a lie"**. That might work without being too extragavant or dramatic.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add another word: *impugn*, which means "to dispute the truth, validity, or honesty of (a statement or motive)" i.e "She **impugned** his pleas of innocence."

It comes from the Latin *pugnare* meaning "to fight", so it's a fairly "aggressive" word.

Answer (score 0):

How about 'unmask'?

You could say 'she unmasked his lies' or 'she unmasked him as a liar'. It has quite a theatrical feeling and is probably more associated with something done publicly than privately between two people.

Comment: I think you'd rather unmask a person than a lie.