# Term for "to undermine scrutiny/conflict by going beneath something"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes "to undermine scrutiny/conflict by going beneath something."

I'm looking for something like:

- Galileo *word*-ed the prevalent idea of Geocentrism by formulating his blasphemous Heliocentrism in secret and proposing it as a result.

I thought the word "subvert" means exactly this because it has "sub" (under) in it; it turns out I was wrong because modern dictionary doesn't note the "going beneath".

Edit: "subvert" is correct as @Lambie pointed out by its etymology ("sub" = to go under, "vertere" = to turn). While I reasoned that the "going beneath" connotation isn't officially added to its definition in modern dictionary, it's my best bet at, at least subliminally, conveying the "going beneath".

Comment: 'Refute' is probably too strong, with the primary sense 'disprove'. As an aside, isn't the idea of Heliocentrism now seen as a convenience when it comes to doing calculations rather than the absolute truth? Is there a huge black hole at the centre of the Universe around which everything rotates? And doesn't Relativity indicate that you can choose any point in space as your origin?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: I don't see your point here. It's a well-documented fact that everything in the solar system revolves around the sun. Kepler's laws of planetary motion are based on this fact— the sun is at one of the foci of the ellipse, and the planet(s) at the other.

Comment: subvert is right; overturn something from its foundation

Comment: user405662 But that is observing from a position outside the 'two points'. You can say that any point you like is the stationary one, and everything else performs weird acrobatics around that point. Think of a Space with just two objects. Which one is moving? //  It has long been argued that it is more realistic to consider the Moon as a twin planet of the Earth: a mass stationary wrt to the spheres' joining axis at certain points along it will head into the Sun rather than towards either the Earth or the Moon.

Comment: @Lambie *subvert* doesn't extend the overturning/undermining to the notion of going underneath something. Although, if I can't identify one, I may have to resort to *subvert* as the closest meaning. I don't know why but I quite often find myself in need of the "going underneath" connotation attached to the "undermining of some structure".

Comment: Of course it does: sub is under and vertere to turn. Furthermore, to say "subvert a notion or idea" is a well-known trope.

Comment: @Lambie I guess you're right since I have a vague sense of "going beneath" on the outset. If what I had in my subconscious isn't "going beneath sth and overturn it", I don't know what else I could've had in mind.

Comment: There's also subsume but that gets into tectonic plates. [caveat: joke]

Comment: @user405662 "It's a well-documented fact that everything in the solar system revolves around the sun." Umm, **no**. In fact, it was Galileo's discovery that Jupiter's moons revolve around *Jupiter* that led to his "blasphemous" claim of heliocentrism.

Answer (score 1):

Are you probably looking for the word **debunked**?

> expose the falseness or hollowness of ([a myth,] an idea or belief).

[[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/debunk)]

Comment: If so, the question is a duplicate of [a word that means to break someone's lie ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/285940/a-word-that-means-to-break-someones-lie-i-want-to-aggressively-point-out-th).

Comment: I agree with @Decapitated Soul here. What I'm looking for is not to emphasize exposing of falseness, although there is a hint of that in "undermine", as much as going underneath that falseness.

Comment: @vsr3y: You probably wanted to mention someone else... I haven't commented here. :P

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, **deconstruct** works better in the given context.

> to take apart or examine (something) in order to reveal the basis or composition often with the intention of exposing biases, flaws, or inconsistencies

*deconstruct the myths of both the left and the right*

— Wayne Karlin

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: While I agree with your definition of "deconstruct", to use it in, say, the Galileo example would be to emphasize "Galileo takes apart what is fundamentally incorrect with Geocentrism" as opposed to the kind of process I'm looking for: "Galileo tries to formulate his own Heliocentrism in secret (by formulating underneath the prying eyes of devout Catholicism) and simply proposes this theory while not actually pointing out what is wrong with Geocentrism (not sure about whether he actually did point out or not but let's say he didn't for the sake of exemplification).